# rsync compare-dest without attributes

Tags: rsync

I'm comparing a remote folder with a local folder and only copy file differences to a new folder.

This is what I use:

```
rsync -ac --compare-dest=/folder/ rsync://remote/folder/ new-folder/
```

My problem is that it also copies files where an attribute like in my case modification time differs.

At first I thought `--checksum` would fix my problem, but as the manpage of Rsync states:

> **`--compare-dest=DIR`**
>   *If a file is found in DIR that is identical to the sender's file, the file will NOT be transferred to the destination directory ... **If a match is found that differs only in attributes, a local copy is made and the attributes updated**...*

Is there a way to omit the attribute check part? In other words only sync files if their checksum differs?

**Note:** I do want to preserve attributes when a file checksum differs (`--archive`).

---

**Edit:** For now I went with a workaround of first indexing the differences with a dry-run

```
rsync -acn --out-format="%n"  rsync://remote/folder/ /folder/ > index_file
sed -i '/\/$/d' index_file  # Ignore folders
```

And then only sync those

```
rsync -a --files-from=index_file rsync://remote/folder/ new-folder/
```

But I still wonder if the same can be achieved in one go with something like `--compare-dest`.